# Windows 10: How to restart network adapter or service from command line?

Tags: dhcp

My Windows10 constantly loses wired Internet connection for no apparent reason (maybe IP DHcp lease time is too short?). What helps is to open the Device Manager and disable the network adapter  (withe black down arrow icon on the toolbar) and then enable it again (with the green up arrow icon). Can I do the same or achieve the same effect of restarting probably some service that handles the connection to Internet, or  in obtainin a new DHcp IP *from the command line* ?

Comment: `netsh lan reconnect`?

Comment: Troubleshoot your router. An Ethernet connection should stay connected for years on end.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you! Please make  this an answer, for you to get reputation if it works In my case I get `The Wired AutoConfig Service (dot3svc) is not running` error, any idea ? BTW, I did not mention  that my adapter is a `USBGigabit  Ethernet.